# Custom variable on textview not showing

Tags: android, kotlin

Ok so I have here my function which is called when you click on the refresh button:

```
 fun refresh(arg: View) {
        thread {
            val cpu = socket.getCPUUsage()
            println(cpu)
            cpuUsage.text = getString(R.string.cpu_usage, cpu)
        } //This is in a thread because without I can't call the socket functions in the socketmanager class. But that shouldn't matter I think
 }
```

The wanted result is (the text of the cpuUsage textview):
CPU Usage: 0,3434343343 (the string from cpu)
The result I get (this is the textview showing:)
CPU Usage:

But if I insert an other variable in:

```
val test = "hello"
cpuUsage.text = getString(R.string.cpu_usage, test)
```

I get the result:
CPU Usage: hello

So the problem must be the cpu string. But I can easily print the string and I get the number I want.

strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">RaspberryConfig</string>
    <string name="cpu_usage">CPU Usage: %1$s</string>
</resources>
```

SocketManger class (the class where I can call the getCPUUsage() function):

```
class SocketManager(address: String, port: Int) {

    private var socket = Socket(address, port)
    private val input = DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())
    private val output = DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())

    private fun makeRequest(request: String) : String {
        output.writeUTF(request)
        output.flush()
        return input.readUTF()
    }

    fun getCPUUsage() : String {
        return makeRequest("cpu_usage")
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay so I just printed getString(R.string.cpu_usage, cpu) and the result was correct. Weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay looks like there wasn't enough space for the string. I just needed to increase the TextView width.